# SMTP: CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication Unsuccessful

Tags: php, html, smtp

I'm trying to send an email every time someone inputs a form on my website but the `SMTP` isn't working. It keeps on showing me this error. The credentials of the email account are correct. Also, I have already tried `SMTPAuth = False;` but still the same result.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];  


    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                
        $mail->isSMTP();                                 
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';  
        $mail->Port = 587;                               
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';        
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
        $mail->Username = 'sender@test.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password';                        // SMTP password


        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('test@test.com', ' Services');
        $mail->addAddress('recipient@test.com', $name);     // Add a recipient


        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                       // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Contact Us Message';
        $mail->Body    = 'Sent a message, This is the message :';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        header('Location: tempage.php');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
?>
```

What is going wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling 2 days with same issue.
After i find this solution. It's working fine.
Try this.

$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
change to
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';